java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
I am trying to use MVVM with Room DB in my android app but getting this exception on the splashActivity.
It was working fine until i added viewmodel and observers
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mBinding: ActivitySplashBinding
    private lateinit var authVM: AuthViewmodel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mBinding = ActivitySplashBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mBinding.root)

        authVM = ViewModelProvider(this)[AuthViewmodel::class.java]

        observeLoginStatus()
    }

    private fun observeLoginStatus() {
        authVM.getUserLoginStatus?.observe(this, Observer { loggedInUser ->
            if (loggedInUser != null) {
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    navigateToMainActivity()
                }, 3000)
            } else {
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    navigateToAuthActivity()
                }, 3000)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun navigateToMainActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    private fun navigateToAuthActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, AuthActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}


It tried debuggin my code and solutions from stack over flow
this is the logcat



Code for AuthViewmodel as the stacktrace is mentioning authViewmodel too:
class AuthViewmodel : ViewModel() {
private var authRepo = AuthRepository()

val getUserLoginStatus: LiveData<User>? = authRepo.getUserLogInStatus()

private val _getUser = MutableLiveData<User?>()
val getUser: LiveData<User?> get() = _getUser

private val _insertUserResult = MutableLiveData<Long>()
val insertUserResult: LiveData<Long> get() = _insertUserResult

fun insertUser(user: User) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = authRepo.insertUser(user)
        _insertUserResult.postValue(result)
    }
}

fun fetchUser(username: String, password: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val user = authRepo.getUser(username, password)
        _getUser.postValue(user)
    }
}

fun updateUserStatus(user: User) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        authRepo.updateUserStatus(user)
    }
}

}
Code for AuthRepo:
class AuthRepository {
private fun getDbInstance(): Task1Database {
    return Task1Database.getDatabase(Task1.getContext().applicationContext)
}

suspend fun insertUser(user: User): Long {
    return getDbInstance().userDao().insertUser(user)
}

fun getUser(username: String, password: String): User? {
    return getDbInstance().userDao().getUser(username, password)?.value
}

fun getUserLogInStatus(): LiveData<User>? {
    return getDbInstance().userDao().getUserLogInStatus()
}

suspend fun updateUserStatus(user: User) {
    getDbInstance().userDao().updateUserStatus(user)
}

}
Code for Task1 where the lateinitProperty error is pointing:
class Task1 : Application(), LifecycleObserver {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    mContext = this
}

companion object {
    private lateinit var mContext: Context
    fun getContext(): Context {
        return mContext
    }

}

}
Code for DB:
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)

abstract class Task1Database : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun userDao(): AuthDao

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: Task1Database? = null

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): Task1Database {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                Task1Database::class.java,
                "app-database"
            ).build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance
        }
    }
}

}

Can you provide full stack trace?

Is this full stack trace? it seems to be incomplete!

The stacktrace you have shared indicates that a late init property has not been initialized.

@sahar-batool How do you inject mContext in your Auth repository?

@Sahar Batool can you provide AuthRepository code?

Sure I did. Added all the classes where the logcat is pointing

you should try using dependency injection to inject the Context, that way you don't need to hold the Context and problem will be resolved.

Please do not provide text as a screenshot. Copy the stracktrace directly in the question as text. It can then be copied and searched.
